# VBA loop to pull cell addresses and sum them in a cell in another master spreadsheetl

Tags: vba, excel, loops, concatenation

I have the following code but it doesn't get to me to quite where I want:

```
Public Sub populateFile()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim fileName As String
Dim path As String
Dim pulledFormula As String
Dim pulledPath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

path = "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Source Files\"
fileName = Dir(path & "*.xlsx*")

Do While fileName <> ""

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & fileName, UpdateLinks:=False)

j = 24

For i = 8 To 16

     With Workbooks("MasterFile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(fileName).Sheets("SummaryTab").Range(Cells(i - 1, j - 21), Cells(i - 1, j - 13))) > 0 Then
        .Cells(i, j - 10).Value = fileName & vbNewLine & .Cells(i, j - 10).Value

            For j = 15 To 23
            pulledFormula = "+" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Workbooks(fileName).Sheets("SummaryTab").Range("C6:K164"), _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 1), Workbooks(fileName).Sheets("SummaryTab").Range("A6:A164"), 0), _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(6, j), Workbooks(fileName).Sheets("SummaryTab").Range("C5:K5"), 0)).Address(External:=True)

            .Cells(i, j).Value = pulledFormula & .Cells(i, j).Formula

            Next j
        End If
     End With
Next i

wbk.Close
fileName = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

So I am trying to pull relevant (based on the index/match) cell addresses from a bunch of files in a directory. The next step is to iteratively add the addresses together with the + sign in the hope that in the end the master spreadsheet can have the sum of all the relevant cells from all the opened files in one cell (and to do this for a bunch of cells as well). The exact problem is that Excel refuses to evaluate the resulting concatenated formula. Would really appreciate any ideas on how to improve this code!

Thanks!

Note: I need to keep the cell addresses in the master file cells so other people can follow those addresses to the feeder files, so I can't use the Evaluate formula.

Comment: `.Address(External:=True)` is not a function of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index()` this is not the proper track.  You are in VBA, use VBA.  It is acceptable to use match to return the correct row and column, then use `Cells(row,column).Address(External:=True)` to return the correct address.  Index is not needed.

Comment: @ScottCraner I agree your way is a more elegant way to write the code. I rewrote it as you said, but it still doesn't quite give me what I want. In both cases I am able to pull output into the cells that looks like this 
+'[File1.xlsx]SummaryTab'!$E$8+'[File2.xlsx]SummaryTab'!$E$8

I would like Excel to show me the number that is the sum of these two references, but excel just leaves it as shown above. If i go into the cell and then press enter, Excel does evaluate the formula to get the number. Ideally, I would get it to do it without me having to manually edit/Enter the cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a recalculation, or non-recalcualtion, issue.

You may use this simple macro to apply F2 + Enter on the currently selected range:

```
Sub ApplyF2()
    Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1
End Sub
```

Can you modify that technique to suit your needs?